# How to set user agent before loading url in new window on javascript

Tags: javascript, user-agent, window.open

I have tried some thing like this in [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/karuna123/zj6xowLL/),

```
(function () {
    navigator.__defineGetter__('userAgent', function () {
        return 'Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; U; CPU iPhone OS 4_0 like Mac OS X; en-us) AppleWebKit/532.9 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/4.0.5 Mobile/8A293 Safari/6531.22.7';
    });
    window.open('https://stackoverflow.com');
} ());
```

But its doesn't override the useragent ? Any idea or suggestions would be helpful

Comment: Your fiddle contains nothing. Did you save the fiddle before posting the link?

Comment: @ReCaptcha Its here http://jsfiddle.net/karuna123/zj6xowLL/

Comment: It worked for me. Which browser did you use?

Comment: Google chorme - v 35.0.1916.153 opens in new window, but not render the mobile view.
Firefox - v 23.0 , opens in another tab of existing window. its also not render the mobile view.

Comment: i got this, working on chrome: Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; U; CPU iPhone OS 4_0 like Mac OS X; en-us) AppleWebKit/532.9 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/4.0.5 Mobile/8A293 Safari/6531.22.7

Comment: @StephanWagner Which browser version you use and os, can you try this in some other browser.

Comment: Newest chrome, newest safari, newest firefox, all print the same as above, Mac OSX 10.7.5

Comment: But in all Browsers it doesn't load the mobile version in the popup. I don't think thats possible as it is a new browser window which renders javascript from scratch

Comment: @StephanWagner If i open https://stackoverflow.com in new browswer window , it should render the mobile view of stackoverflow.com . How should i do it with override the user agent.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/58860/discussion-between-karan-and-stephan-wagner).